# Translating in R in 2022, translateR or deeplr?

Tags: r, translate, language-translation, deepl

Looking to translate columns in a data frame from english to french, and it looks like translateR has been archived, and deeplr does not have the translate_df function anymore? Can anyone confirm a package that is currently operational that can do this?

I have been trying the translate_df() function from https://github.com/paulcbauer/deeplr but R can't find the function when the package is loaded...

`Error: 'translate_df' is not an exported object from 'namespace:deeplr'`

And the github page references a newer version https://github.com/zumbov2/deeplr which doesn't have a direct df function.

I have done everything I can think of (installing and reinstalling, restarting R, checking libpath, etc.) Any suggestions for an alternate package (or a fix if you're familiar) would be helpful!

Answer (score 1):

For helping any one faces this issue, Here is my package `gtranslate` which translates between different languages for free using Google translate api.

```
install.packages("gtranslate")
```

Or you can install the development version of gtranslate from [GitHub](https://github.com/mohamed-180/gtranslate) with:

```
# install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("mohamed-180/gtranslate")
```